# Is it necessary to install Xcode on Mac to run R?

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I receive an error message: The "git" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?
When I click on install it tells me: Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update Server.
I read somewhere that this can be solved by installing Xcode and then the command line tools. However, as Xcode takes about 10gb of storage I'm a bit reluctant to do it. Is it necessary to install Xcode or is there another way around it (OS version 10.15.7)?

Comment: The title says "R" but your question implies "git" - which one is it?

Comment: When opening R the message pops up: The git command requires the command line tools etc

Comment: What happens if you just try to install `git` on its own?

Comment: The command line tools are available as a standalone download from developer.apple.com. I believe you need to be logged in with a (free) Apple ID. The download is called "Command Line Tools for Xcode 12".